# What are the .NET Micro Framework ready systems available?

Tags: system, .net-micro-framework, netduino

Once I heard of [Netduino](http://netduino.com/) I began to wonder which other systems would provide the same features:

- Processor and Memory Micro .NET Framework ready
- USB interface
- Cheap
- Portable

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207597/cool-hardware-devices-that-can-be-programmed-in-net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[TinyCLR](http://www.tinyclr.com/) produces several different boards that support the .Net Micro Framework, the most popular was once the [Fez Domino](http://www.ghielectronics.com/catalog/product/133), now deprecated and replaced by the [Fez Panda II](http://www.ghielectronics.com/catalog/product/256):

[image]

> FEZ (Freakin' Easy!) is a tiny open-source board running Microsoft .NET Micro Framework. This means, you can write code with much more efficiency using C# programming language under free Microsoft Visual C# express. Build your next projects in minutes by connecting FEZ Domino to one of the shields or the many available components. Includes USB cable.
>
> Many libraries are already included like FAT file system, threading, USB Client, USB Host, UART, SPI, I2C, GPIO, PWM, ADC, DAC and many more.
>
> FEZ offers many features not found in Arduino, BASIC STAMP and others:
>
> - Based on Microsoft''s .NET Micro Framework.
> - Runs on 72Mhz NXP ARM processors.
> - Supports runtime debugging (breakpoints, variable inspection, stepping, etc.)
> - Use [Visual C# 2010 Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CS) for development.
> - Advanced capabilities like FAT, USB device and USB host.
> - Easily upgrades to hardware such as [EMX](http://www.ghielectronics.com/product/128).
> - Open source hardware design files.
> - Use existing shields and holder boards.
> - Based on the [USBizi chipset](http://www.ghielectronics.com/product/116) (ideal for commercial use).
> - [FEZ Mini](http://www.tinyclr.com/hardware/2/fez-mini/) is [BS2](http://www.parallax.com/) pin-out compatible with extra I/Os.
> - [FEZ Domino](http://www.ghielectronics.com/catalog/product/133) is [Arduino](http://arduino.cc/) pin-out compatible with extra I/Os.

Comment: It costs $74.95

Comment: User free FLASH About 148KB, User free RAM About 62KB

Comment: The firmware is not open source, which has always put me off.

Answer (score 4):

Complementing "O Engenheiro" answer:

[GHI EMX US$ 299.95](http://www.ghielectronics.com/product/129)
[image]

- 72 MHz 32-bit ARM 7 Processor
- 16MB RAM and 4.5MB FLASH
- 320 x 240 3.5" TFT Display with touch screen.
- RJ-45 Ethernet connector.
- GHI WiFi-Expansion compatible.
- Standard JTAG connector (only available for GHI partners).
- TFT signals exposed.
- GPIO signals with interrupts exposed on 0.1" header pins with on-board pin descriptions.
- 2 SPI Master bus (8/16bit).
- I2C interface.
- 4 exposed UART (serial ports), one RS232 interface with hardware handshaking.
- 7 analog inputs (ADC), 2 are used with touch screen.
- 1 analog output (DAC).
- 2 CAN interfaces, CAN 1 is connected to CAN PHY with 9-DSUB interface.
- 6 PWM signals.
- One-wire interface support
- SD/MMC card connector with spring.
- USB Device port
- USB Host port
- XBee module socket.
- UEXT interface for easy expansions such as GPS, MP3 decoder or 3-axis accelerometer.
- Real Time Clock backup battery.
- LEDs and push buttons.
- On-board Piezo.
- Powered by USB or DC power (input 6 volts through 2.1mm power connector).

[Tahoe-II](http://devicesolutions.net/Products/TahoeII.aspx) [US$ 399.00](http://app.arrownac.com/aws/pg_webc?s=P)

[image]

- Meridian CPU (ARM920 @ 100MHz)
- 8Mbytes SDRAM and 4Mbytes Flash
- 3.5” Landscape TFT LCD with touch-screen
- 9 user input buttons
- RS232 serial (DB9)
- USB Function
- Ethernet
- Accelerometer, with support for event notification including free-fall detection
- SD Card interface
- Temperature sensor and 2x ADC channels
- Interface for XBee wireless module (and additional ADC channels if fitted)
- PWM output
- Expansion connectors that expose GPIO, I2C, SPI and UART signals

Answer (score 3):

I'll also post about [Netduino US$ 34.95](http://netduino.com/netduino/), a open source platform

[image]

Processor and memory

- Atmel 32-bit microcontroller
- Speed: 48MHz, ARM7
- Code Storage: 128 KB
- RAM: 60 KB

digital i/o features

- all 20 digital and analog pins: GPIO
- digital pins 0-1: UART 1 RX, TX
- digital pins 2-3: UART 2 RX, TX
- digital pins 5-6: PWM, PWM
- digital pins 7-8: UART 2 RTS, CTS
- digital pins 9-10: PWM, PWM
- digital pins 11-13: SPI MOSI, MISO, SPCK
- analog pins 4-5: I2C SDA, SCL

Comment: You've talked about Netduino on your question.

Comment: Currently in public beta, the Secret Labs team is planning to ship the [NetDuino Plus](http://netduino.com/netduinoplus/specs.htm) by the end of the year.  The two main additions are built-in ethernet and micro-sd support.

Answer (score 3):

- [Tahoe 2](http://devicesolutions.net/Products/TahoeII.aspx)
- [GHI EMX](http://www.ghielectronics.com/product/129)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a recently announced system. **It may not be available for purchase yet**.

[The .NET Gadgeteer](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/gadgeteer/default.aspx)

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/gadgeteer/gadgeer_modules.png

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/gadgeteer/gadgeteer_example.jpg

Comment: Where can I buy it?

Comment: I suspect that you can't buy it. Contact Microsoft Research, perhaps it's going to be open source...

Comment: Channel 9 said "Sometime next spring" though OEM's.  Does that mean Spring 2011?